# how to grab the max of common columns with partition in sql

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

i have this Table Chips:

[image]

im looking to find the max for each ID but 
the code im using is just not correct i need the new table to be

[image]

```
  select * 
  from
  (
     max (numchips) over (partition by Id)
     from @chips
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
 SELECT Id, numchips 
 FROM (
     SELECT Id, numchips, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id 
                               ORDER BY numchips DESC) as rn
     FROM @chips
  ) t
  WHERE rn = 1
```

`rn` is equal to `1` for the record having the highest `numchips` value within each `Id` partition.

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` makes sense only if you have some *additional* columns in `Chips` table that you also want to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just do?:

```
SELECT 
   MAX(c.numchips), 
   c.Id 
FROM 
   @chips as c
GROUP BY 
   c.Id
```